# Move table data to next row in table after a button click in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a two tables totally **Table1** and **table2**. **Table1** is filled with data from a service. In **Table1** I have columns such as Qty,Price and Checkbox. In the **checkbox** column I have checkboxes as values. The **qty** and **price** have number as values In table2 I have columns named Qty and Price.

Now say if I click the checkbox in row 1,2 in **table1**. So if you take the **Qty** column in **table1** all the **Qty** values in row 1,2 will be added and be shown in qty column in **table2** as a single value. Same goes for **price** column. (Example 6,4 are the values of qty column in row 1,2 so add(6+4) and show total in first row of **qty** column in **table2**.
**Table1 when checked:**
[image: Table1 when checked]

**After clicking gettotal button**

[image: After clicking gettotal button]

I have also deleted the rows of the particular checkboxes which I have already selected or enabled in **table1** and have summed up in **table2** in first row. All these functionalities happen after a **button** click. So after the **button** click a new row is formed in **table2** and the enabled checkboxes have been deleted in **table1**.

Now what happens is that for the next time if I enable next set of checkboxes on **table1** and then click the **button** again, instead of forming a new row the values gets overwrited in the first row of **table2**. I wanted the next set of total from **table1** to be added as a next row(in **table1**) instead of overwriting or replacing the values in the first row in **table2**

**Next set of checkboxes**

[image: Next set of checkboxes]

**Table2overwrited**

[image: Table2overwrited]

**Note** :This code was done with the help of stackoverflow user Vimalpatel. I give him full credits to for the code in the stackblitz. I have Tried my best to explain. Pls comment below if my question is unclear

**Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xj8tw4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use a list of type `TotalCount` and then iterate over the list using `*ngFor` as you did with **Table 1**.

```
totalCount: any[] = [];
```

**getTotalCount()**

```
  getTotalCount() {
    let tC = new TotalCount();
    this.listes.map(item => {
      if (item.isChecked) {
        tC.qty = tC.qty + item.qty;
        tC.value = tC.value + item.value;

        this.listes = this.listes.slice(item.isChecked);
      }
    });
    this.totalCount.push(tC);
  }
```

and the html:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let totalCount of totalCount; index as j">
        <td>{{j+1}}</td>
        <td>{{totalCount.qty}}</td>
        <td>{{totalCount.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mx1ygl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) should help.